# How to make keybinds in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in a server and I have a rank that allows me to use chat colors but you need to type &F(Text) to enable white. I was wondering if there is a way to make is so that when you press a key it will auto type &F but not send it into chat so that I can type after it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not gaming specific. Macros/autotypers/keyboard automation works for all programs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this natively within Minecraft, but you can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com), which lets you assign key combinations to certain commands or messages. There's a beginner's tutorial on their site [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s1).